# High Cassandra CPU Usage Inspection

Tags: performance, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 version in my cluster. I see high CPU usage even though when i check "nodetool tpstats" result says that there is no active and passive pending requests. How can i inspect that?

Additionally, other nodes in the datacenter idle, no CPU  usage

Comment: try out https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop ?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144280/cassandra-running-compact-indefinitely-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: @ChrisLohfink thanks to the program i see  the main problem. It is not related directly to cassandra. I use software package, the problem is related to that software.

Comment: @Yılmaz were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: It's been long time. My cluster has 3.11.x version of cassandra. maybe you'd better upgrade your cluster than solving this problem. maybe it's the only solution @ErikPerik